# sitecore ecommerce shopping cart onchange event

Tags: e-commerce, sitecore

I'm having an issue with sitecore e-commerce since I'm very new to it. Is there a possibility to perform some actions when new product is added to shopping cart. In other words is there a possibility to know when the list of products in shopping cart has changed?

Comment: hi, what have you tried until now ?

Comment: You could use javascript (json) to trigger a shoppingcart update through an .aspx page for example.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is. Because you are using Sitecore ;) , it is easy to create your own ShoppingCart class which inherites from the Sitecore ShoppingCart class. Within your custom ShoppingCart you can create any functionality that you want. Also you can create custom events or override Sitecore events with your own customized code.

Unfortunately I don't have an ECommerce project at hand at this moment, but I recently worked on an ECommerce project and I frequently used Reflector to look inside the Sitecore ECommerce .dll's to see how they handled certain actions and used that info to create custom actions/events etc.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an event system built in to the Sitecore Ecommerce cart. However there is a cart event API available in the Active Commerce module, which extends Sitecore Ecommerce.

http://www.activecommerce.com/